# Task 'prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel' not found in project

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have this error in my project `Task 'prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel' not found in project`  I was looking at it online and found that adding the following lines will fix it

```
task prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel {

}
```

I tried adding the above to build.gradle.kts and following error ocured.

`Function invocation 'task(...)' expected`

I also tried `tasks.register("prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel"){}` which did not work too

what is the correct way of writing a task please.

thanks for your help in advance

thanks
R

Answer (score 2):

This was occurring for me when I tried to add a new subproject to my main project.

I solved the issue by unlinking the project I had added manually then 'refreshing' the parent project the sub-project was inside. See this issue:

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/14889#issuecomment-988134777